# string reverse in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string

For example, my input is `my name is abcd`
I need to display as `dcba si eman ym`
I have done below which is giving an output as `abcd is name my`
but have no idea what to do next

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a string: ");
    string[] input = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');

    for (int i = input.Length-1; i >=0; i--)
    {
        Console.Write(input[i]+" ");
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: If you're reversing the string, what purpose does splitting the string into "words" serve? Just call [ToCharArray()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.tochararray.aspx) on the string (which will give you the characters) and then iterate through those characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this this will work perfectly. I think this is what you have been looking for!

```
string Str, reversestring = "";
        int Length;
        Console.Write("Enter A String : ");
        Str = Console.ReadLine();
        Length = Str.Length - 1;
        while (Length >= 0)
        {
            reversestring = reversestring + Str[Length];
            Length--;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Reverse  String  Is  {0}", reversestring);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

My Fiddle example: [Reverse with Words and Text](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iK2u2i)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the API - Array.Reverse

```
char[] charArray = input.ToCharArray();
Array.Reverse( charArray );
reversed = new string( charArray );
```

Answer (score 1):

What your code do is reversing the initial string by words, like this:

```
my name is abcd --> abcd is name my
```

To change this you need to read the whole string and use it as char array:

```
var input = Console.ReadLine();
var sb = new StringBuilder(input.Length);
for (var i = input.Length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
{
    sb.Append(input[i]);
}
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Also you can use the [`Array.Reverse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3877932.aspx) method:

```
var input = Console.ReadLine();
var charArray = input.ToCharArray();
Array.Reverse(charArray);
var reversed = new string(charArray);
Console.WriteLine(reversed);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `.Split(' ')` in `string[] input = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');`

You can simply read the entire line with `string input = Console.ReadLine();` then reverse the entire line.

If you look at the below link it provides two options.

1. Reverse the entire string using a `Array.Reverse`
2. loop through every character from the end to the start and output it.

https://www.dotnetperls.com/reverse-string#d

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ's Aggregate function to reverse a string

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter a string: ");
string input = Console.ReadLine();
input = input.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (j, k) => j.Insert(0, k)).ToString();
```

The Aggregate prepend each Char to the reversed string

Answer (score 0):

```
        public static string RevString(string str)
    {
        var charArry = str.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(charArry);
        return new string(charArry);
    }
   public static string RevString2(string str)
    {
        string revString = "";
        foreach( char c in str)
        {
            revString = c + revString;
        }

        return revString;
    }

    //no change to the order of the words
    public static string RevString3(string str)
    {
        string[] strArray = str.Split(' ');

        string revString = "";
        foreach (string s in strArray)
        {
            var charArray = s.ToCharArray();
            Array.Reverse(charArray);
            revString +=  new string(charArray) + " ";
        }

        return revString;
    }
    public static string RevString4(string str)
    {
        string[] strArray = str.Split(' ');

        string revString = "";
        foreach (string s in strArray)
        {
            string revWord = "";
            foreach(char c in s)
            {
                revWord = c + revWord;
            }
            revString += revWord + " ";
        }

        return revString;
    }
```

Comment: You should use a minute or two to explain what your code is doing

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use "string.Reverse()" method like so:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a string: ");
    string[] input = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');

    for (int i = input.Length-1; i >=0; i--)
    {
        input[i] = string.Join("", input[i].Reverse());
        Console.Write(input[i]+" ");
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
Still the "words[i].Reverse()" returns an IEnumerable() so you still need to use string.Join(), but at least this way you get to write less cod
```